# Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 46

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, security, logins

I am facing the below error :

- Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' :
- Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database.
- Reason: Failed to open the database configured in the login object while revalidating the login on the connection.

Few points here :

1. Login NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM has SYSADMIN Role along with Public Role
2. Default Database is Master for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Login .
3. Master DB is Online and AutoClose is False
4. The Database which the login is trying to access is a temporary Database and is in Single user mode for last 15 days failing with above error.
5. When I check SP_HELPDB it doesnot show the Database where as SYS.Database shows the database in name column ?
6. When I tried to set MULTI_USER it says DB is already open and can have only one user at a time and database is in single user mode .

I have checked Aaron Bertrands post on login issues and found below :

[image]

Please help me what else I am missing ?

Do I need to change the default database to the database which the login is trying to access ?

Please advice .

Comment: what you want to Exact looking from "sp_helpdb' & 'sys.databases';

Comment: The error codes mentions about database availability and accessibility , so I am looking for the DB status .

Comment: ,what DB status? login default 'database' or else?

Answer (score 4):

> Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database.
>
> ...
>
> The Database which the login is trying to access is a temporary Database
> and is in Single user mode for last 15 days failing with above error.

The error clearly says that the database specified in the connection string cannot be accessed.

So you have these possibilities:

- change the connection string with master database
- make your database accessible, put it in `multi_user`

Answer (score 2):

With the points mentioned , it seems your database is already connected by some login and since it is in Single-User mode, you are not able to access it.

> 6.When I tried to set MULTI_USER it says DB is already open and can have only one user at a time and database is in single user mode .

Try making the db to Multi-User from the GUI and not via script in query window.Also run sp_who2 and try to terminate the connection which is accessing the database now. Once the database is accessible to all users, it will not throw the error you have mentioned.